# shell script to copy file

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ubuntu-12.04

I have create a shell script to copy all file have the same root. I have been googling and find a solution but it can not work:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/From_folder/

for f in *.drl
do 
   cp $f /home/To_folder/${f%.drl}$(date +%m%d%y).drl
done
```

Is there any another solution ?
thankyou very much

Comment: please post an example on how it should work. e.g outputfilename for `aaa.drl`

Comment: Put `#!/bin/bash -vx` as the first line and try again.

Comment: And how is this related to java and tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

I have test your script, change it like this for easy testing:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /tmp/From

for f in *.drl
do
   cp $f /tmp/To/${f%.drl}$(date +%m%d%y).drl
done
```

And it works! So may be you are a normal user, and can not go into other users' home dir, so the script not work. show me error output!
please check if you can go into the dir /home/From_folder and /home/To_folder, I means that if you are not root, you can NOT go into other normal users' home dir.

Comment: I have 2 test drl file and it's log when I execute script--- cp: cannot create regular file `/home/To_folder//home/From_folder/test1.drl': No such file or directory      cp: cannot create regular file `/home/To_folder//home/From_folder/test2.drl': No such file or directory

Comment: error output like 'cp: cannot create regular file /home/To_folder//home/From_folder/test1.drl': No such file or directory' should not happen, if your script surely like 'cd /home/From_folder/;
for f in \*.drl', and if your script like 'for f in /home/From_folder/\*.drl' , the error output is like that. Use my script code, test it again.

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
cp * /path/to/your/folder
```